# Set NixOS config option only when it is valid, for backwards compatibility

Tags: configuration, nixos, compatibility

Occasionally, NixOS changes config options in a way that is not entirely backwards compatible. For example, nixos 19.09 did not have a `programs.gnupg.agent.pinentryFlavor` option, but in nixos unstable (soon 20.03) I need to set it to a non-default value in order to get the right pinentry variant.

I share my configuration across machines, some of which run nixos-19.09 and some nixos-unstable, so I want my configuration to be compatible with both. (even without multiple machines, it would be nice to be able to switch nixos channels without breakage)

Setting `programs.gnupg.agent.pinentryFlavor = "gtk2";` as needed for nixos-unstable causes `nixos-rebuild` to fail on nixos-19.09:

```
error: The option `programs.gnupg.agent.pinentryFlavor' defined in `[...]/desktop.nix' does not exist.
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

Is there a way to check if an option is valid?

Essentially, I'm looking for what to write in place of `???(pinentryFlavor)`) here, so as to not set a nonexistent option:

```
programs.gnupg.agent = { enable = true;} // (
  if ???(pinentryFlavor)
  then { pinentryFlavor = "gtk2"; }
  else {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration function does receive an `options` attr, so it is possible to check if a given option is defined using `builtins.hasAttr` before setting it in the configuration.

Most NixOS configurations don't extract `options`, so you may need to add it first. For example:

```
{ config, pkgs, options, ... }:
{
  programs.gnupg.agent =
    { enable = true;  } //
    # False on NixOS 19.09
    (if builtins.hasAttr "pinentryFlavor" options.programs.gnupg.agent
     then { pinentryFlavor = "gtk2"; }
     else {});
}
```

Similarly, the same approach can be used to set options used by `nixos-rebuild build-vm`, which would normally not be available.

Instead of needing to set options via environment variables when running the VM like

```
QEMU_OPTS='-m 4096 -smp 4 -soundhw ac97' ./result/bin/run-*-vm
```

the equivalent options can be set in configuration.nix:

```
  # The default 384MB RAM is not enough to run Firefox in a VM
  virtualisation =
    lib.optionalAttrs (builtins.hasAttr "qemu" options.virtualisation) {
      memorySize = 4096;
      cores = 4;
      qemu.options = [ "-soundhw ac97" ];
    };
```